# Single '}' encountered in format string

Tags: python, mysql

I have a usertable with a column 'routes' that has values like `'[{"407": "410"}, {"410": "408"}]'`. I need to select all rows that have values 408"}, so I'm using like keyword in 
MySQL to achieve this. The query looks as below
select routes from usertable where routes like `'%408"}%'`

This query works in MySQL Workbench, but when I take this to Python its not working, my query looks like below in Python
`(select routes from usertable where routes like`'%{1}"}%').format(routes)`

The error I see is as below:

```
    "Single '}' encountered in format string"
```

I did try using escape characters i.e. `\"` and `}}` but still getting the same error.

Please suggest how to fix this.

Thanks,
Seema

Answer (score 4):

`'%{1}"}%'.format(routes)'` should be `'%{1}"}}%'.format(routes)'` (note the double `}}`).

that is how you can convice `format` not to try and fill a value but to return just one `}`. as stated in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

> The parts of the string outside curly braces are treated literally,
>   except that any doubled curly braces '{{' or '}}' are replaced with
>   the corresponding single curly brace.

Answer (score 2):

You should duplicate `}` and `{` if you intend to use formatting.

In your case, edit your string so it looks like that `'%{1}"}}%').format(routes)`. This will give results you expect.

---

As for

> I did try using escape characters

It seems you tried to escape characters you use for format, not the ones you don't mean to touch.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following query

```
select routes from usertable where routes like '%%{{\"{1}\"%%'".format(routes))
```

The **%** that you are using is **escape character** you can use %% for instead of **%** (similarly instead of **{** use **{{** and add \ before " ).

This will help you.